# R & ggplot2: Sparklines from dynamic variables (based on query results)

Tags: r, visualization, ggplot2

I've written an SQL query that tells me the names of the previous week's top 10 most frequent Alarms. And I've written a query that takes those top 10 alarms and provides a YTD weekly totals for each of those alarms.

Now I'm looking to create a panel of sparklines showing the YTD trend for each of the week's top 10 alarms.

I got something resembling what I'd like, but I now need to make it "dynamic". i.e. to make it work without hardcoding the names of the alarms (since these will change with the SQL query every week).

How can I go about changing the R code below to work without hardcoding the names of the alarms?

Does levels(spark$Alarm) have something to do with?

Thanks kindly for the advice :-)

```
Week = c(rep(1:8,2))
Total = rnorm(16,1000,600)
Alarm = c(rep("BELTWEIGHER HIGH HIGH",8), rep("MICROWAVE LHS",8))
spark <- data.frame(Week, Alarm, Total)

s <- ggplot(spark, aes(Week, Total)) +
     facet_grid(Alarm ~ ., scales = "free", as.table = FALSE) +
     opts(
  panel.background = theme_rect(size = 1, colour = "lightgray"),
  panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
  axis.line = theme_blank(),
  axis.text.x = theme_blank(),
  axis.text.y = theme_blank(),
  axis.title.x = theme_blank(),
  axis.title.y = theme_blank(), 
  axis.ticks = theme_blank(),
  strip.background = theme_blank(),
  strip.text.y = theme_text(size = 7, colour = "red", angle = 90)
 )

s1 <- s  + geom_line(subset = .(Alarm == "BELTWEIGHER HIGH HIGH"))
s2 <- s1 + geom_line(subset = .(Alarm == "MICROWAVE LHS"))
s2
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434760/sparklines-in-ggplot2/35436104).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay that was a dumb question :)

Here's the obvious answer.

```
Week = c(rep(1:8,2))
Total = rnorm(16,1000,600)
Alarm = c(rep("BELTWEIGHER HIGH HIGH",8), rep("MICROWAVE LHS",8))
spark <- data.frame(Week, Alarm, Total)


s <- ggplot(spark, aes(Week, Total)) +         
     theme(
        panel.background = element_rect(size = 1, colour = "lightgray"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_blank()
        #strip.text.y = element_text(size = 7, colour = "red", angle = 90)
    )

s + facet_grid(Alarm ~.) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Not dumb, although it was hard to tell what "Alarms" are in your particular application. The only difference is that you used facetting?

Comment: Hi Lao, i m using same code but i m getting Error: No layers in plot
Execution halted. want to generate spark lines. many thanks.